# Why Is My Label Returning 0, 0, 0 + Strange Error About Array Size, When Everything Checks Out?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm mind boggled.

Everything seems to check, and yet, it's not working.

When testing it, by adding a label to get three values from the array, no values were stored in the array. I also receive the error: "Study Error
Error on bar 10: Array is too large. Maximum
size is 100000."

Yet, the bar index of the current bar is around 17,000. Nowhere near 100,000 of the array limit.

Why is it not working? What's wrong? How can we fix it? Thank you so much!

Code in question:

```
// Establish loop numbers.

CurrentBarIndexRealtime = bar_index //This is around ~17,000 (Nowhere near the 100,000 array limitation. Hmm.)
LookbackForTotalArraySize = (365 * 24) 
FirstBarIndex = CurrentBarIndexRealtime - TotalDurationPeriod365Days1hr + 1 

CurrentBarIndex = CurrentBarIndexRealtime 

// Test data retrieval from plotted labels.

val1 = array.get(Array15, 5)
val2 = array.get(Array20, 25)
val3 = array.get(Array25, 55)

label.new(bar_index, high, "Values: " + str.tostring(val1) + ", " + str.tostring(val2) + ", " + str.tostring(val3), color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up)
```

Answer (score 1):

In pinescript to initialize the variables only one time at the beginning, you should use `var`.

In your code, yours arrays are initialized on each bar, this ways, they are empty.

You should replace your declarations lines with :

```
var PercentageHighDataArray = array.new_float(LookbackForTotalArraySize, 0.00)
var PercentageLowDataArray = array.new_float(LookbackForTotalArraySize, 0.00)
```

Comment: @TheLegendOfA in StackOverFlow, you question and answer will be used in the future by other people. That's why you should ask only one question with one problem. Your question was 'Why Is My Label Returning 0, 0, 0 When Everything Checks Out?' I think we solved this issue.

Comment: Hi, I did this. It still returns 0, 0, 0. Thanks! I even updated the code. And now there's an error saying it cannot plot due to it reaching over 100,000 bars, and it's nowhere near this limit.

Comment: Yup, just confirmed. As soon as I add "var" to it, the error appears. When I remove "var", the error disappears, but, 0, 0, 0 shows on the label plot again.

Comment: ok, 1) it is another problem, so you need to open another question. 2) with the extract of code you provide, we can't help you, please share the entire code in your new question so that we can help you.